# ImportXML formula parse error

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I am a beginner and I am trying to import Author's name from the amazon website using

```
=IMPORTXML(URL,'//*[@id="byline']/span/span[1]/a[1]")").
```

It shows parse error. Please help me fix this or let me know if you know some other way.

I am trying for below mentioned link: 
[https://www.amazon.com/True-Conviction-Adrian-Hell-ebook/dp/B00IC46HYO/ref=zg_bs_157055011_f_4?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=83TW112AQC8CND0RPX86](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IC46HYO)

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the url into A1, the correct syntax may looks like: =IMPORTXML(A1;"//div[@id='byline']/span/span[1]/a[1]")

But moreover, pay your attention to this post:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88218/importxml-google-spreadsheet-amazon-review-numbers

It can be difficult to do this :(